# According to Area51, askubuntu.com is in public beta/private beta

Tags: bug, status-completed

The [proposal page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7716/) shows Ubuntu in a mix of states ("Public beta"/"Public beta begins soon!").

The site, however, has fully launched, becoming the first Area51 site with its own real domain. Congratulations!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good catch.  This is fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

The slightly early launch of Ask Ubuntu to coincide with the release of Ubuntu 10.10 has made this happen. No doubt it will be fixed soon! (But meanwhile I don't suppose Area 51 is the main way new visitors will be finding us...)

Comment: I know it's not important, it's a bug nonetheless :)